# What is some advantage and disadvantage to had 9-in W x 9-in L Stainless Steel Square Chimney Cap

Tags: ventilation

What is some advantage and disadvantage to had 9-in W x 9-in L Square Chimney Cap welding on top of the 18 in W X 18 in L Square Chimney Cap with a circular opening on the top side and then install to the top of the Chimney? I asked this because it seems to me the gas doesn't vent out too well.

Both square Chimney Cap is similar to the below picture.

[image]

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Why are you welding two chimney caps together?

Comment: @tyson It is partially due to allow more room for the gas to vent out

Comment: If you're having chimney draw problems, you should ask about how to solve that instead.  Those chimney caps are engineered with 360degree ventilation. They can't be preventing exhaust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros to capping are reduction of rain entering, prevents birds and squirls from nesting in chimney you can see when you need to have the chimney swept.
cons reduces draft , provides a place for cresode to accumulate ( further reducing draft and looks ugly when there is buildup) .
In some areas where builders cloth was required due to fire danger we installed wind driven directional caps to increase draft. I don't think the large holes in the photo will meet the requirement if needed for fire risk.
Now understanding there are 2 caps from OP comment, I think this will increase the area for draft and take longer for cresode to build up so this is probably a good idea. I can't see where it would hurt.

Comment: Thanks You for your answer. Sorry but you partially misunderstanding my question. I weld two cap together due to allow more room for the gas to vent out. Therefore this question is asking is it good idea to weld two caps together. Thanks in advance for revise your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Helps prevent downdrafts
2. Spark arresting

Comment: It will help keep out rain water, birds bats, and the occasional critter .